# Question about Normal/Tangential coordinates

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I have been told that position is a vector. It goes from the origin to the object that is moving.
If that vector is a function of time, its first derivative gives the velocity vector and its second derivative gives the acceleration vector.

Now in n/t coordinates, the origin is the center of the object. Wouldn't that imply that the position vector is zero at all instants, and that the velocity and acceleration vectors are also zero at all times ? I know of course that this is wrong because we can express the velocity and acceleration vectors in n/t coordinates.

Please explain to me how the position vector is zero and the velocity is not.

Comment: Different context but same answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/113605/4-velocity-and-4-acceleration-in-instantaneous-rest-frames. The point is that the coordinate system is changing as the particle moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal/tangential frame is a frame of reference that is fixed on the object.

It should be obvious that if the frame of reference is the object, the object cannot have any displacement in that frame of reference, because the object cannot move away from itself.

Relative to it's own reference frame, it will have *no* velocity and *no* acceleration.  But there's a problem when it comes time to look at the Newtonian physics.  Newtons laws are based on *inertial* reference frames.  If the object is experiencing an acceleration, it is no longer an inertial reference frame, and in it's own reference frame, it will experience inertial effects ([fictitious forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force)).

If the object is moving with only a constant velocity, then the physics in it's frame of reference will apply as well as in another inertial frame of reference.  In the objects frame of reference, stationary objects will appear to have a velocity relative to the object, and any analysis of relative movement between the two will be accurate in either reference frame.  If the object is accelerating, any other relative movement will be accounted for by the fictitious forces that the object experiences in it's non-inertial frame.

Comment: Does that mean that in the n/t coordinates the origon is not the object ?

Comment: @NaderYouhanna No.  I mean that in the N/T frame of reference the origin is always the same location as the object, and if the origin is moving with the object, obviously the object cannot move _relative to that frame of reference_.

Comment: I can't really understand the distinction between a frame of reference that is fixed on an object, and one that *is* the object. Isn't it the same thing  ?

Comment: @NaderYouhanna I didn't mean to imply any difference between them.  A frame of reference that _is_ the object is really just a frame of reference fixed on an object; both mean the same thing as far as I intended.

Comment: Alright so if I understand well, velocity and acceleration measured from an object's frame of reference are zero, but have non-zero magnitudes when measured from frames of reference outside them. Is that right ?

Comment: @NaderYouhanna Yeah, exactly.  And the physics still works as long as you account for the fact that your frame of reference is moving when you do the math.

Comment: But how then can we say that velocity and acceleration are zero in the frame of reference of the moving object, and still have a N/T frame of reference with its origin at the object's centre ?

Comment: Wouldn't that jist imply v and a are zero in N/T frame of reference ?

Comment: @NaderYouhanna If I understand what you're asking, yes.  The N/T frame of reference is a frame of reference that follows the moving object, and a and v are 0 in that frame.

Comment: But that's not what I was told in the Dynamics class. We learnt that in N/T frame of reference, acceleration has a tangential component and a normal component, and that for example a_n=v^2/R and so on, so the velocity and acceleration are not zero

Comment: @NaderYouhanna I don't think I completely understood what you were asking then.  In a frame of reference that _isn't_ the moving object, you can measure that the object has an acceleration.  You can also look at the normal and tangential components from the reference frame of the object, and in that frame (and only in that frame) it has no relative velocity or acceleration.  It still has velocity and acceleration relative to other things, such as whatever it is traveling tangentially around.  That is the acceleration that that equation calculates.

Comment: Oh so that means that the normal component of acceleration, for example, is just the projection of the acceleration vector on the unit vector that is normal to the path u_n, and *not* the projection of the acceleration measured from the object's frame of reference on u_n ?

Comment: @NaderYouhanna Yeah, exactly.  I can understand now why this must have seemed so confusing.  Often times you will look at those accelerations from the point of view of the moving object; but the values for acceleration and velocity are considered relative to something that isn't moving, not the snapshot that we are looking at.

Comment: That clears it up, thanks a lot  ❤️❤️