# Three velocity and three acceleration of particle

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration, velocity

The following is written in $c=1$-units. Imagine that a particle is moving on a world line, parametrically described with its proper time as follows:
$$t(\tau) = b^{-1}\sinh(b\tau) \text{   ;   } x(\tau) = b^{-1}\cosh(b\tau).$$
$b$ is a positive constant. In this reference frame the components of the four velocity is then given by,
$$u^{\alpha} = (\cosh(b\tau), \sinh(b\tau), 0, 0),$$
and the four-acceleration is given by
$$a^{\alpha} = (b\sinh(b\tau), b\cosh(b\tau), 0, 0).$$
In order to gain physical insight in these quantities, I used the following Lorentz transformation given by its matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} cosh(b\tau) & -sinh(b\tau) & 0 & 0 \\ -sinh(b\tau) & cosh(b\tau) & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
This transformation causes the four velocity to become
$$u'^{\alpha} = (1, 0, 0, 0)$$
which I think means that the three-velocity of the particle is zero. The four-acceleration becomes
$$a'^{\alpha} = (0, b, 0, 0)$$
Now I am confused about the physical details of the motion of the particle because in this new reference frame the three velocity is zero, which I thinks means that the particle is at rest in this reference frame. However the particle is now accelerating in the $x$-direction with amount $b$. So how can we be at rest with the particle, yet it is still accelerating? Is there something I am interpreting wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forget about relativity. Do you understand how a particle can have zero velocity but non-zero acceleration?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, but in this case how can it at all times have zero velocity and non zero accelerarion if its moving in de $x$ direction only?

Comment: This probably answers your question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113605/

Comment: @lukiluk The transformation you used isn't a Lorentz transformation, because the parameters depend on $\tau$ (they aren't constant). Therefore you are not moving into an inertial reference frame. Instead you are transforming into an accelerating reference frame that moves with the particle. A particle at rest in an accelerating reference frame is accelerating with respect to an inertial frame. There's more details in the answer Pipe linked to.

Comment: @Pipe yes thank you! I think i get it now.